# Absolute Positioning Trouble with Dropdown Submenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, position, absolute

I cannot get a absolutely positioned submenu to position properly. Furthermore, there seems to be something off with the padding, and I cannot figure it out.

The code is here:

https://codepen.io/CusterMonroe/pen/WWZZEV

```css
.med-max-show li:not(.dropdown){
list-style-type: none;
background:#222F37;
padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.med-max-show li a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
display: block;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.med-max-show{
text-align: center;
padding: 0 0 1px;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,color-stop(0, #3c3c3c),to(#222));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
border-top: 2px solid gold;
border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
}

.med-max-show > ul{
margin: 0 auto;
width: 70%;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown{
display: inline-block;
width: 30%;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,color-stop(0, #3c3c3c),to(#222));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#3c3c3c 0,#222 100%);
text-align: center;
padding: 6px 0 6px;
margin-top: 1px;
position: relative;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown:hover > a{
color: gold;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown-menu{
border-top: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
background: #222F37;
padding: 0px 0px 1px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 10pt;
width: 100%;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition-property: visibility;
-o-transition-property: visibility;
transition-property: visibility;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
     -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
     -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
z-index: 99999999999999999 !important;
opacity: .95;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.6)
}

.med-max-show .dropdown:hover > ul{
visibility: visible;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown-menu a{
padding: 4px 50px 4px 50px;
margin: 1px 0 1px;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown-menu a:hover{
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom,#f1ecec 0,#fffbfb 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(to bottom,#f1ecec 0,#fffbfb 100%);
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear,left top, left bottom,color-stop(0, #f1ecec),to(#fffbfb));
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f1ecec 0,#fffbfb 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f1ecec 0,#fffbfb 100%);
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#f1ecec 0,#fffbfb 100%);
color: black;
}

.submenu-left{
position: relative;
display: block;
}

.submenu-right{
position: relative;
display: block;
}

.submenu-left ul{
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
right: 100%;
top: -1px;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition-property: visibility;
-o-transition-property: visibility;
transition-property: visibility;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
     -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-right ul{
position: absolute;
left: 100%;
top: -1px;
width: 108%;
margin-left: -23px;
visibility: hidden;
-webkit-transition-property: visibility;
-o-transition-property: visibility;
transition-property: visibility;
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
     -o-transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-duration: 1s;
display: block;
}

.submenu-right ul li a{
width: 100%:
}

.submenu-left > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
          box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.submenu-right > ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
          box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.submenu-left ul li{
border-top: 2px solid black;
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.submenu-right ul li{
border-top: 2px solid black;
padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.submenu-left:hover > ul{
visibility: visible;
}

.submenu-right:hover > ul{
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Custerism</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="submenu-right"><a 
       href="javascript:void(0);">PHILOSOPHY</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">CUSTERISM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">BEEKIN</a></li>
                <li class="submenu-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);">HELP 
         TOPICS</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">DRAGONSPEAK</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">PATCHES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">GENERAL 
        KNOWLEDGE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">NEWS</a></li>
```

I am pretty sure it is something to do with my CSS somehow. I just cannot figure out what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

commented  `margin-left: -23px;` and added  `padding: 0;` of `.submenu-right ul`

```css
.med-max-show li:not(.dropdown) {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #222F37;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.med-max-show li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.med-max-show {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 1px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #3c3c3c), to(#222));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  border-top: 2px solid gold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gold;
}

.med-max-show>ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #3c3c3c), to(#222));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3c3c3c 0, #222 100%);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 0 6px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: relative;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown:hover>a {
  color: gold;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown-menu {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  background: #222F37;
  padding: 0px 0px 1px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: visibility;
  -o-transition-property: visibility;
  transition-property: visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  z-index: 99999999999999999 !important;
  opacity: .95;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)
}

.med-max-show .dropdown:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown-menu a {
  padding: 4px 50px 4px 50px;
  margin: 1px 0 1px;
}

.med-max-show .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1ecec 0, #fffbfb 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1ecec 0, #fffbfb 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f1ecec), to(#fffbfb));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f1ecec 0, #fffbfb 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f1ecec 0, #fffbfb 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f1ecec 0, #fffbfb 100%);
  color: black;
}

.submenu-left {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.submenu-right {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.submenu-left ul {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  right: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: visibility;
  -o-transition-property: visibility;
  transition-property: visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  display: inline-block;
}

.submenu-right ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  width: 108%;
  /* margin-left: -23px; */
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition-property: visibility;
  -o-transition-property: visibility;
  transition-property: visibility;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
}

.submenu-right ul li a {
  width: 100%:
}

.submenu-left>ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.submenu-right>ul::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px;
  width: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
  box-shadow: 0 15px 30px black;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.submenu-left ul li {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.submenu-right ul li {
  border-top: 2px solid black;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

.submenu-left:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

.submenu-right:hover>ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="med-max-show">
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0);">In Character</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">PROFILE</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">JOURNAL</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-left"><a href="javascript:void(0);">JOIN ME</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">RP FORUM</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="">Out of Character</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">HANGOUTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">GUESTBOOK</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Custerism</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="submenu-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);">PHILOSOPHY</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">CUSTERISM</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">BEEKIN</a></li>
        <li class="submenu-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);">HELP TOPICS</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">DRAGONSPEAK</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">PATCHES</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">GENERAL KNOWLEDGE</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">NEWS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I THINK I LOVE YOU, BUT WHAT AM I SO AFRAID OF!?!?!??!?! THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! (=

Comment: I have a question. Why was padding the issue? Why wouldn't margin be the issue? Is it because the absolute tag inside a relative tag becomes part of the content in the box model of the relative tag?

Comment: `padding-inline-start: 40px;` css was getting applied to `ul` tag to override it i used `padding`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the time to search and tell you the "why" this is happening, but there is something to do with the user agent.

Furthermore, just add this CSS code to your file:

```css
.submenu-right ul {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

This is going to reset the styles authored (possibly) by the user agent. In this way, you'll have the desired style.

Besides that, I'd recommend you to learn and play with browsers development tools, as with this knowledge I was able to find and silence the bug, easily.

Comment: That did help, but with 100% to the left, the submenu is over the relative parent element.

Comment: Which browser are you using to find the bug? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Me too. I'm using chrome.

Comment: @Custer You're using too many hacks, like in "width: 108%". I could go look to solve these others problems, but this is beyond this topic. For now, again, just learn how to use browsers debug tools properly (chrome is the most used, although firefox is much better).

Comment: I'm gonna watch a Youtube video to better learn about the console for Chrome. Any good references? Thanks! (=

Comment: @Custer This official channel seems to be perfect and they provide many videos on the matter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=6&v=H0XScE08hy8. Before that, make sure you know what is the box model, DOM, BOM, etc.

Comment: @Custer Make sure to upvote people answers, if they helped you in some way. Also, have you tried to run your code locally? I suspect that this has something to do with Code Pen.

Comment: I always run my code locally; this was the first time using Code Pen, actually; I utilized Code Pen to illustrate my code better. (-:

Answer (score 0):

the João Lucas answer almost

```
.submenu-right ul {
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

plus

```
.med-max-show > ul{
  padding-inline-start: 0;
}
```

Comment: These work great in Chrome, thanks! But when I checked Internet Explorer and Edge, they don't work. That's why I had to add those hacks like 108% width and -23 margin.

Comment: Thanks, again, my dude, for taking time to answer my question, which offended someone enough to give it a down vote. ;p